# Can someone tell me why this isn't working?

Tags: c

So I'm making a program to scan the name and grades of a number of students and then show me all of the students with an average of 85+.
I'm required to use structures and the instructions say I have to dynamically allocate memory for the names with the help of the strlen function.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

typedef struct stud
{
    char *name;
    int marks[4];
    float avg;
}student;


student* Create_Class(int);
void Avg_Mark(student*);
void Print_One(student*);


int main()
{
    int size, i;
    student *arr;
    printf("\nEnter the number of students: ");
    scanf("%d", &size);
    arr = (student*)malloc(size * sizeof(student));
    arr = Create_Class(size);
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        if ((arr + i)->avg > 85)
            Print_One(arr + i);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
        free((arr[i].name));
    free(arr);
    return 0;
}

student* Create_Class(int size)
{
    struct stud *Arr;
    int i, j, k;
    char YourName[51];
    int length;
    Arr = (struct stud*)malloc(size * sizeof(struct stud));
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        printf("Enter your name: ");
        scanf(" %s", YourName);
        length = strlen(YourName);
        (Arr + i)->name = (char*)malloc(length * sizeof(char));
        for (k = 0; k < length; k++)
            (Arr + i)->name[k] = YourName[k];
        (Arr + i)->name[k] = '\0';
        printf("Enter your marks: ");
        for (j = 0; j < 4; j++)
            scanf("%d", &(Arr + i)->marks[j]);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
        Avg_Mark(Arr + i);
    return Arr;
}


void Avg_Mark(student* s)
{
    int i;
    float sum = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        sum += s->marks[i];
    }
    s->avg = sum / 4;
}


void Print_One(student* s)
{
    printf("The average of %s is %.1f\n", s->name, s->avg);
}
```

It seems the problem is with freeing the name field pointer in the main function.
Can someone tell me what went wrong?
The code itself is pretty straightforward so if anything is unclear feel free to ask and I'll try to be as detailed as possible.

Comment: You do `arr = ...` directly followed by `arr = ...` (the right-hand side of the assignment is irrelevant). Think about what you're doing there for a little while.

Comment: As for your problem, you seem to remember that strings needs to be terminated, but you *never allocate space for the terminator*.

Comment: What exactly makes you think there's a problem?  Is the program not outputting the correct results?  Is there an error?  Tell us.

Comment: There is an off-by-one bug in this code, it corrupts the heap.  You must allocate length+1 chars to ensure there is enough space for the final zero.  A secure CRT function like strpy_s() helps you discover bugs like this.

Comment: On another but unrelated note, for any pointer `p` and index `i`, the expression `*(p + i)` is *exactly* equal to `p[i]`. That means instead of `(Arr + i)->name` you can do `Arr[i].name`. Means *exactly* the same thing, but is shorter to write, easier to read, and easier to understand.

Comment: @jwodder Sorry I forgot to mention that if I try running it as it is it crashes, whereas if I delete the loop for releasing the name pointers it runs fine, but I can't leave any unreleased pointers(I have to free them).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thanks I'm fairly new to structures so I'm still getting the hang of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two issues in your code.

1. You are overwritting the `arr` memory by calling `create_class`

   `arr = (student*)malloc(size * sizeof(student));
   arr = Create_Class(size);`

   This will lead to memory leak, so just remove     `arr = (student*)malloc(size * sizeof(student));`.
2. You are not allocating enough memory to your `name` field.

   `length = strlen(YourName);
    (Arr + i)->name = (char*)malloc(length * sizeof(char));`

   should be `length = strlen(YourName)+1;` to hold `null` char.